# Does the alternate installer (12.04) allow dual booting in Windows (resizing partition)?

Tags: 12.04, windows, partitioning, dual-boot, alternative

I can not use the Desktop 12.04 CD on a laptop with Windows. I can use the Alternate CD (12.04) on this computer, but I am unsure if the alternate CD allows re-partioning the hard disk allowing a dual boot with existing Windows partition.

Does the alternate installer (12.04) allow to create a dual boot with Windows (resizing partition)?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**  ,you can Re-Partition thereby allowing your system to be able to dual boot.

The Alternate CD also allows more advanced installation options which are not available with the Standard LiveCD.

Pleas follow this [**Illustrated page for Alternate Cd installation.**](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p2.html).

Here's the partitioning option image from the above link

[image]

From above **DO** select the **Manual** option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the alternate installer supports repartitioning and therefore dual boot.

Check out this [video](http://youtu.be/Xi-VPj4jzrg) for a "video walkthrough" of the installer. Partitioning starts at around 3:26.